# Unresolved reference: string

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When creating a reusable top app bar, `string` became unresolved. Is there additional code that is needed to fix this?

> Unresolved reference: string

```
@Composable
fun MyTopAppBar(
    title: String,
) {
    var showMenu by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    LargeTopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(
                text = title,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                maxLines = 1,
            )
        },
        actions = {
            IconButton(onClick = { showMenu = !showMenu }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.MoreVert,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.more_options)
                )
            }

            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = showMenu,
                onDismissRequest = { showMenu = false }
            ) {
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(text = stringResource(R.string.settings)) },
                    onClick = {
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: If you mean `R.string`, did you add an `import` for your `R` class?

Comment: 'androidx.compose.material3.R' was automatically added but interestingly I didn't need it for the main activity.

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm interesting...........................

Answer (score 10):

R.string should be imported with an import containing your package name such as :

```
import com.mycompany.myappname.R
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new package, you may need to declare its namespace in your build.gradle.kts file. For example:

```
android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapp.feature.newpackage"
}
```

Don't forget to "Sync Project".